# If else to check for multiple conditions but one text input

Tags: python

I am trying to create a take-off on a 3-Cup Monte Program. Students using Brython in CodeHS Ide to draw "cups" and a white ball that will randomly appear in one of the cups. That part is working. However, when the user guesses by typing input: left, right or middle, the console should print the input and either 'You Guessed It' or 'Bad Answer'. But the answer always comes up as 'Bad Answer' even when the ball is in the correct cup or not.

Screenshot of game :
[game table with cups. user input is 'left', the ball is in the correct(left) cup, yet program prints 'Bad Answer'][1]

Here is my code so far:

```
def func_left():
    left_ball = Circle(36)
    left_ball.set_color(Color.white)
    left_ball.set_position(80,200)
    add(left_ball)

def func_middle():
    middle_ball = Circle(36)
    middle_ball.set_color(Color.white)
    middle_ball.set_position(200,200)
    add(middle_ball)
    
def func_right():
    right_ball = Circle(36)
    right_ball.set_color(Color.white)
    right_ball.set_position(320,200)  
    add(right_ball)
    
my_list = [func_left, func_middle, func_right]
random.choice(my_list)()




guess = (input(" Do yo think the ball is under the left, middle, or right cup?: "))
print (guess)

if guess == "left" and func_left:
        print("You Guessed It!")
        
if  guess == "middle" and my_list == func_middle:
        print("You Guessed It!")

if guess == "right" and my_list == func_right:
         print("You Guessed It!")
else:
    print("Bad Answer!")


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au66d.png
```

Comment: You assume "guess" is one of those three, but what if it's not? Also, random.choice has a return value. Those three functions all exist, but that doesn't mean they were chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use if, elif, else structure

```
if guess == "left" and func_left:
        print("You Guessed It!")
        
elif  guess == "middle" and my_list == func_middle:
        print("You Guessed It!")

elif guess == "right" and my_list == func_right:
         print("You Guessed It!")
else:
    print("Bad Answer!")
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that and it tells me the answer is correct every time no. matter what cup the ball is in and if it I s in the correct cup it tells me Bad Answer.

Comment: maybe it's because the first condition have "and func_left" and not "my_list == func_left"?

Comment: also I think you don't want to condition on the value of my_list but on the value of random.choice(my_list)

Comment: Thank you again. Yes, I did forget to put the my_list in and I fixed that. I also tried random. choice(my_list) and that gives the same bad results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
def func_left():
    left_ball = Circle(36)
    left_ball.set_color(Color.white)
    left_ball.set_position(80,200)
    add(left_ball)
    return 'left'

def func_middle():
    middle_ball = Circle(36)
    middle_ball.set_color(Color.white)
    middle_ball.set_position(200,200)
    add(middle_ball)
    return 'middle'

def func_right():
    right_ball = Circle(36)
    right_ball.set_color(Color.white)
    right_ball.set_position(320,200)  
    add(right_ball)
    return 'right'

my_list = [func_left, func_middle, func_right]
random_choice = random.choice(my_list)()

guess = (input(" Do yo think the ball is under the left, middle, or right cup?: "))
print (guess)

if guess == "left" and random_choice == 'left':
        print("You Guessed It!")
        
elif  guess == "middle" and random_choice == 'middle':
        print("You Guessed It!")

elif guess == "right" and random_choice == 'right':
         print("You Guessed It!")
else:
    print("Bad Answer!")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. I was too tunnel vision to see it

Comment: We have been working 1/2 the night to find a good way to write a loop to allow the user to replay this game instead of having to click the 'run' button on the ide. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use while True loop. Put under the while True loop (infinite loop) the whole code after the function defining part. And at the end of it, you can ask for an input asking if you want to replay. If yes, continue the loop else if no, then break the loop. (Please don't mind my english)